# Iphone app PNG sequence animation - How to use OPENgle optimally without crashing

Tags: iphone, opengl, animation, png

i am making an animation in opegle with pngs and considering to use the highest qaulity compression and not use pvr conversion.

Does anyone know the maximum amount of frames you can do before the processor starts getting chuggy? and i have a series of frames
i would also note that my png sequence is roughly 75 frames and many in which are being repeated to help out.

all the best,
charlie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you are doing is animating through 75 PNG images, you might want to skip OpenGL, and just use the built in "animationImages" on UIImageView.

[Here's an example](http://www.appsamuck.com/day2.html)

Comment: but for up to 75 png images? do you think that might chug the processor and crash?

Comment: I'm not sure - I would be more worried about memory than the processor personally, but it doesn't take much code to just try it out and see if it would work.

Comment: so, heres the solution i have come up with. im using alphaPng sprite sheets (1024x1024), jammed my sequence here and using a combination of PVR opengle2 animation for the background that is constant. im realizing now that, the more unique frames you use in a png animation will take a lot of time to download. so, with use of sprite sheets and open GL2 pvrs, im created an animation of about 71frames, with pretty much 2 png sprite sheets 512x512, 1pvr sequence that is about 71frames (i did lose qaulity but its coming out ok), then a couple custom UIgraphic elements. not bad for 3-4 sec download.

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView Animation Images will work !